# Common fields for different django models in one place

Tags: django

I have some columns that are repeated in multiple models. is there any solution to place them somewhere and use it any model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating base classes and inheriting them in your models.

Example:

```
class TimestampsModel(models.Model):

    @classmethod
    def get_fields(cls, fields: tuple):
        return fields.__add__(('created_at', 'updated_at'))
    
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(("created_at"), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(("updated_at"), auto_now=True)
```

You can also make it abstract and Django won't create migrations for this.

```
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Finally, a model would be:

```
class Blog(baseModels.TimestampsModel):

    class Meta:
        db_table = "blog"

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Yes. this is what I need.