# Common fields for different fastapi models in one place using pydantic models

Tags: model, fastapi, pydantic

I am using fastapi framework and creating models using Pydantic.I have a 2 models customerProfileShort and CustomerProfileLong .Among these models 6 fields are common .Is there is a way we can define the fileds at oneplace and reuse them in any of the models.

## define them at one place like this

address: Optional[str] = Field(example="4849 William Terrace")

use the same in different models

I have to do in this way ?? or any simpler way ??

```
class First_name(BaseModel):
    first_name: str = Field(None, example="John")
class Last_name(BaseModel):
    last_name: str = Field(None, example="Doe")
class Actions_Count(BaseModel):
    actions_count: int = Field(None, example=131)
class Event_performed(BaseModel)
    action_name: str Field(None, example="check out")
class Address(BaseModel):
    address: Optional[str] = Field(example="4849 William Terrace")
class State(BaseModel):
    state: Optional[str] = Field(example="NC")
class Country(BaseModel):
    country: Optional[str] = Field(example="US")
    
class ShortCustomerProfile(Address,Actions_Count,Last_name,First_name):
        pass

Class State_Counts(State,Country):
        pass

class Events_Performed_By_Customer(First_name,Last_name,Event_performed):
        pass
```

I am using fastapi framework and creating models using Pydantic.I have a 2 models customerProfileShort and CustomerProfileLong .Among these models 6 fields are common .Is there is a way we can define the fileds at oneplace and reuse them in any of the models.

## define them at one place like this

address: Optional[str] = Field(example="4849 William Terrace")

use the same in different models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pydantic supports inheritance in the same as way as any other Python classes. It's also [given as an example in the FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#add-an-output-model). You can do this by creating a base model that you then inherit from (and you can do this in as many layers as required, but be careful to not make the code incomprehensible).

```py
class CustomerProfileShort:
    address: Optional[str] = Field(example="4849 William Terrace")


class CustomerProfileLong(CustomerProfileShort):
    more_information: str
```

Python also supports multiple inheritance so you can "compose" a resulting model from many other, smaller models based on what they should support. But again, be careful not to overdo it, as that will just makes your code harder to follow and understand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .But my requirement would be if I change the type of address in one place it should reflect everywhere.I want to use them as a field in different models rather than using those 3 as a model

`class CustomerProfileShort(BaseModel):
    

    first_name: str = Field(None, example="John")
    last_name: str = Field(None, example="Doe")
   address: int = Field(None, example=131)
# example code 
class NewImpl(BaseModel):
 name:first_name # expecting the first_name to be str from CustomerProfileShort
more_details:str = Field(None, 'XXXXX')`

Comment: If you change `address` in the base model, the change will be reflected in all subclasses. Are you asking how you can define custom _types_ instead? Because in your original question you asked about six fields being common and having them present in your other models.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70055888/common-fields-for-different-django-models-in-one-place
 Want to do the same in fastapi

Comment: That's the exact same concept as the one I explained. What's the difference? "You can achieve this by creating base classes and inheriting them in your models."

Comment: I'd try to avoid doing that, what you're effectively doing is just make each field composable from different subclasses. Instead try to group relevant fields together, so that you have `class HasAddressMixin(BaseModel):` with fields that are relevant if the object has an address, `HasNameMixin(BaseModel)` if the object has firstname/lastname/etc. You just end up with your definition being spread out over a large area and changes having unforeseen consequences. You have to read through a looooong list of inheritance instead of having the field entries right there.

Comment: This seems to effectively be a concept attempting to be a solution to an imaginary problem in the future, with a large cost in being able to understand and parse code at the current time.

Comment: Hey Can you check once .I have added more details in my question